# Access Denied for Web API OData endpoint hosted using OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, wcf-data-services, access-denied, httplistener

I have a Web API which works beside WCF service on the same port as instructed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988675/sharing-the-same-port-for-wcf-rest-and-asp-net-web-api). I have registered the URL for WCF using `base URL` for both services say `http://+:80/a/b/` using netsh.

> WCF route is `http://+:80/a/b/v3`
>   WebAPI route is `http://+:80/a/b/v4`

This is hosted within `windows service`. WCF endpoints work fine.
OWIN host gives `HttpListenerException : Access Denied`

When i run `netsh http show urlacl` it has registered only WCF endpoint but not WebAPI's.
It works fine when i register using

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/a/b/v4/ user="NT SERVICE/MyService" listen=yes

Queries i have:

> - How come WCF is reserving URL but not WebAPI?
> - How can i reserve URL as WCF does without netsh in WebAPI?
> - I can't have endpoint tag defined in config for webapi, can i?

Thanks in advance :)